# How to detect network changes using Node.js

Tags: node.js

How can I listen for changes in the network connectivity?

Do you know any implementation or module that accomplish this?

I'm wondering if exists something similar to:

```
  reachability.on('change' function(){...});
  reachability.on('connect' function(){...});
  reachability.on('disconnect' function(){...});
```

I've googled it and couldn't find anything about it.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such functionality built-in to node. You might be able to hook into the OS to listen for the network interface going up or down or even an ethernet cable being unplugged, but any other type of connectivity loss is going to be difficult to determine instantly.

The easiest way to detect dead connections is to use an application-level ping/heartbeat mechanism and/or a timeout of some kind.

If the network connectivity detection is not specific to a particular network request, you could do something like this to globally test network connectivity by continually pinging some well-connected system that responds to pings. Example:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter,
    spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    rl = require('readline');

var RE_SUCCESS = /bytes from/i,
    INTERVAL = 2, // in seconds
    IP = '8.8.8.8';

var proc = spawn('ping', ['-v', '-n', '-i', INTERVAL, IP]),
    rli = rl.createInterface(proc.stdout, proc.stdin),
    network = new EventEmitter();

network.online = false;

rli.on('line', function(str) {
  if (RE_SUCCESS.test(str)) {
    if (!network.online) {
      network.online = true;
      network.emit('online');
    }
  } else if (network.online) {
    network.online = false;
    network.emit('offline');
  }
});



// then just listen for the `online` and `offline` events ...
network.on('online', function() {
  console.log('online!');
}).on('offline', function() {
  console.log('offline!');
});
```

Comment: The workaround that I'm using is an application-level ping using the module 'dns' and calling 'resolve'(since I need my App to be able to reach a specific domain and not a specific IP).
I'm using like this:
1 - process.nextTick calls a function to try to resolve a dns.
2 - Whether it manage to resolve or not I trigger the specific event.
3 - The function called by process.nextTick runs indefinitely

It works, but...
**Should I stick with this approach? Is there something wrong with it?**

Thank you

Comment: I guess it depends on your needs. If you need that kind of fast response I suppose that should be ok, but if you don't need to know *that* quickly, you could delay the check so it only checks every second for example. Along the same lines, you could also spawn a child process that just does a never-ending `ping -v` to some well-connected system that responds to pings. Then parse the output looking for ICMP errors.

Comment: I'm doing exactly this. The function tries to resolve dns each 2 seconds. I'm gonna try the latter approach. Do you know any good resource as a reference to implement what you mentioned? I'm starting in the Node.js world.
Thank you

Comment: I've updated my answer to include an example using `ping` (at least on Linux).

Comment: Is there any package that listens native connection changes rather than `ping` approach? For example [NotifyAddrChange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366329(v=VS.85).aspx) on Windows?

Comment: This is sad.  The whole reason for detecting network connectivity is to avoid the need to *poll* which is what things like ping are.  OSes have gotten so good at detecting this that they sometimes border on being *intrusive* in letting you know about it, so the fact that an application can't detect this is just sad.

Comment: And to add onto this, in javascript browsers have been able to detect being offline for a while, in a way that appears to use network changes detection, so node.js seems to be behind the curve in this regard.  Of course this answer is now 4 years old, so maybe (hopefully) this comment is actually out of date?

Comment: @Michael The keyword there is _browsers_ have such ability. It is not a part of the JavaScript language itself, so it would be up to node to include such functionality. Otherwise if you want a non-polling solution you will need to write/use a compiled node addon to hook into OS-specific mechanisms.

Comment: Problem with this approach is that network interface switches, which usually are fast, will remain unobserved if happening between pings